# Pause recording and continue from where left off in Ableton Live 11

Tags: audio-recording, ableton-live

While recording a song, sometimes we want to listen our recordings and then we want to continue the recording from where I left off.

And while recording the next part we need to play the previously recorded from middle of the  track to catch the next line (I hope I have made it clear)

In this particular scenario, I just wanted to press start recording from middle of the previously recorded line, so it will play the song and track which will help to catch the next line. The recording should start from where I left off automatically. But if I do so it might overlap when I press recording from middle of the previously recorded line.

It might be confusing but I have tried to explain my issue in simpler way.

In studio the recordist do the same for ease of recording. If I have missed anything please let me know. I'm not sure how much clearity is there in my question. Please help me to learn this feature in Ableton Live lite 11

Comment: What you are asking about sounds like punch-in with pre-roll and auto switch on the recording track from play to input. But I'm not sure I understand clearly your use case.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-Ecr4stvXbR

sir please visit the we transfer link i have created a video and explained what i need to do.